# Ruby on Rails thin server hangs in development mode after first page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, thin

I want to be able to develop a rails application that runs in SSL and Non-SSL mode at the same time without needing to restart the server to see modifications to the application and without needing apache or another server in the middle.  The application is meant to be a control panel to configure and build apache so a third party server in the middle isn't an option.

I setup the rails development server with thin (and nodejs) and it hangs after the first page load if config.cache_classes = false .

At first I solved the hanging problem by adding config.threadsafe! to the end of development.rb file.  When I started making an application the server wasn't applying my changes without a restart. When I add config.cache_classes = false after the config.threadsafe! the server returns to hanging after the first page load.

How can I stop the server from hanging after the first page load and still be able to see changes made to applications without needing to restart the server?

```
Ruby 1.9.3
Rails 4.0.3
Debian 7.4 (Wheezy)
```

thin.yml

```
user: appuser 
group: appuser 
pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid
timeout: 30
wait: 30
log: log/thin.log
max_conns: 1024
require: []
environment: development
max_persistent_conns: 512
servers: 1
threaded: true
no-epoll: true
daemonize: true
port: 2082
chdir: /path/to/app
tag: myapp aux
```

development.rb

```
DControlPanel::Application.configure do

  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  config.threadsafe!
  config.cache_classes = false

end
```

/etc/init.d/myapp

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: myapp
# Required-Start: $local_fs $remote_fs $syslog $named $network $time
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $remote_fs $syslog $named $network
# Default-Start: 3 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: myapp applications
# Description: myapp applications
### END INIT INFO
# Author: Name <email@domain.tld>
user="appuser"

railsstart() {
load_rvm="source /home/$user/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
thin="bundle exec thin -C config/thin.yml"
thinssl="bundle exec thin --ssl -C config/thin-ssl.yml"

path="/path/to/app"
command=$1
echo "$load_rvm && cd $path && $thin $command && $thinssl $command"

}


# Aktionen
case "$1" in
start)
exec sudo -u $user bash -c "`railsstart start` "
;;
stop)
exec sudo -u $user bash -c "`railsstart stop`"
;;
restart)
exec sudo -u $user bash -c "`railsstart restart`"
;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: how did you 'set up the development server'? Are you using the inbuilt `rails server`?

Comment: Did you enable caching? Do you have config.action_controller.perform_caching = true in your development. rb file?

Comment: I recommend just using `rails server` if you're just starting out with Rails - it will get you going faster and you can worry about server issues later.

Comment: @sevenseacat I need the server to run a ssl and non-ssl version at the same time, without apache in the middle. Is that possible without thin?

Comment: @sevenseacat I did try it to see what would happen "rails server -c config/rails.yml" but that leads to ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:42:in `require': cannot load such file and the rails.yml file does exist and is readable and writable by the user

Comment: As of now I'm just starting with "rails server" which is somewhat useless to me since I shouldn't need to manually start a new server every time I'm going to make changes, but it is better than nothing.

Comment: what is `config/rails.yml` and where has it come from? It's not a standard Rails thing. And with webrick, you won't need to restart the server unless you change things like app or gem configuration.

Comment: The config/rails.yml a configuration file I created like the one above, but to be used for the non-ssl version. I quickly found the "rails server" doesn't provide start/stop capability anyhow so it won't integrate properly with my sysv init. I've commented out config.cache_classes = false for now and am considering using Java/JSP for this project instead since Java doesn't have these problems.